# Map an array, but sorted by values inside the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting, mapping

I have an array like this:

```
[{ "title": "Home", "url": "/", "order": 1 },
{ "title": "Services", "url": "#services", "order": 2 },
{ "title": "Blog", "url": "#blog", "order": 3 },
{ "title": "About", "url": "#about", "order": 5 },
{ "title": "Our Work", "url": "#ourwork", "order": 4 },
{ "title": "Studio", "url": "#studio", "order": 7 },
{ "title": "Get in touch", "url": "#contact", "order": 6 }]
```

I need to map the array to display menu links. I would normally just write something like this:

```
{menu.map((item, index) => (
  <a key={index} href={item.url}><span>{item.name}</span></a>
))}
```

But the links need to appear in the correct order.

What is the easiest way to sort it before mapping? Or is there a way to directly use the map function and have them appear sorted by order value?

Comment: `.map()` is not going to help with sorting. You can of course use `.sort()` to order the values before mapping.